# How to print results with signs when calculation is done on array in C language

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to do SPI transfer in a raspberry pi. Raspberry pi comes with an SPI interface which send and recieves the data through it GPIO(General purpose input output pins). The spi driver information is  [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.12.y/drivers/spi/spi-bcm2708.c). I am doing loopback (connect MOSI and MISO pins). I had describe in my code what data I am sending, This data I will recieve due to loopback. I want a calculation on the recieved data. These data are stored in the form of array. After the calculation I need to print the results with proper sign, but I am not getting it.Here is my complete code.

```
/************************All header should come here************************************************************************     ********************************/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
/***************************All declaration should come here***************************************************************************************************/

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
static const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";//selecting spi device in the raspberry pi
static uint8_t mode;//mode of spi transfer
static uint8_t bits =8;//no. of bits to be transfer, Pi supports 8 bit transfer 
static uint32_t speed = 32000000;//spi clock speed,32 MHz is the maximum supported clock frequency
static uint16_t delay;

/*****************************Function definition should come here**********************************************************************************************/

/*function for transfer*/
static void transfer(int fd)//declaring a function for the transfer, this should be call in main program for transfer
{
int ret;// a return variable
uint8_t  tx[]={4,5,6,5,4,3,5,4};// Array initialization
uint8_t  rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)]={0,};//recieving array should be same as  transferred array
 struct spi_ioc_transfer tr= { // standard structure for spi driver usage
       .tx_buf=(unsigned long)tx,//transmitting buffer
       .rx_buf= (unsigned long)rx,//recieving buffer
       .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),//length of trasnmitting buffer
       .delay_usecs=delay,
       .speed_hz = speed,
       .bits_per_word= bits,
       };


 ret = ioctl (fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);//comm. is done by ioctl     command, This initializes the transfer
 for (ret=0;ret< ARRAY_SIZE(tx);ret++){//recieving the data in rx buffer and rx array size is same as tx array size
    if (!(ret%4))//meant for printing process
    puts("");
   printf("%d\t %X\n",ret, rx[ret]);//formatting



 }//herer return is used as an index for the recieving array

printf("\n");


 float x=((rx[1]+rx[3])-(rx[0]+rx[2]))/(rx[0]+rx[1]+rx[2]+rx[3]);
//x[1]=((rx[5]+rx[7])-(rx[4])+rx[5])/(rx[4]+rx[5]+rx[6]+rx[7]);

printf("%f\n",x);

}//end of function for the transfer


 /************************Main Program****************************************************************************************************************************/


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){// start of main

int ret=0;//initializing return
int fd;// a file handle to handle the device as a file
fd=open (device,O_RDWR);//fd handles this device with read and write permission
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE,&mode);
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE,&mode);
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD,&bits);
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD,&bits);
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ,&speed);
ret=ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ,&speed);
transfer(fd);//transfer of data begins
close(fd);//close the file handle, it has opened earlier
return ret;
 }
```

I Just need my output with proper sign after calculation on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you honestly think that how the data came into `printf()` matters? It really doesn't, `printf()` has no idea that you're using SPI, of course.

If all you want is the plus/minus to appear (instead of just the minus for negative values), reading [the manual page for `printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) tells us:

> +
>   A sign (+ or -) should always be placed before a number produced by a signed conversion. By default a sign is used only for negative numbers. A + overrides a space if both are used.

So, you should use:

```
printf("%+d\t%+d\n", x[0], x[1]);
```

Comment: ((rx[1]+rx[3])-(rx[0]+rx[2]))/(rx[0]+rx[1]+rx[2]+rx[3]) is equals to (13-12)/16 which is -0.0625 But it is not what I am getting, I am getting 0 instead

Comment: @vivek that is because integer value of `-0.0625` is `0`.You are using `%d` to print.

Comment: @vivek If you want to use real numbers, you need to use floating point numbers. An int (same for `uint8_t`) can only store integers.

Comment: @GauravSehgal thats true integer truncates the digit before decimal point. After replacing %d with %f and declaring x as float, I am still getting tha same 0

Comment: @vivek That's because all of the `rx` values are integers too, the calculation doesn't care about the type of the left-hand side. In C, `float x = 3 / 4;` is 0.

Comment: @unwind I made it as float  tx[]={4,5,6,5,4,3,5,4};and float  rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)]={0,} but in output I am getting only two rx array element rx[0]and rx[1].

Comment: @vivek You should re-submit the true question that's hiding here, it's quite hard to follow. Please read the [MCVE page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @vivek Your edited question is still massively long, and very far from being a minimal example as the link defines it. And you still have `rx` as `uint8_t`.